# Adding Element to a Specific Linked List of Linked Lists in C

Tags: c

Suppose we have the following structure:

```
typedef struct link {
    char link[MAXLINK];
    struct link *next;
} LinkT;

typedef struct node {
    char keyword[MAXKEY];
    LinkT *links;
    struct node *next; 
} NodeT;
```

In the main function I have added few new keyword and links to it. The output I'm getting when printing the whole list is:

```
Asteroid
    Link-45
    Link-23
Earth
    Link-2
Moon
    Link-3
    Link-1
```

I would like to add a new link-4 to the Earth. So the output would look like this:

```
Asteroid
    Link-45
    Link-23
Earth
    Link-2
    Link-4
Moon
    Link-3
    Link-1
```

My idea was to have a `findLink` function that traverse through the list of keywords, and then ones keyword matches, traverse through the links list and if no link was found, I add new one.

However, the problem is when I run the below code, it never finishes, does not output anything (freezing?) and I have to force exit it.

If I remove the last added keyword and links, it runs but not correctly and prints that link is not in list. Similar function `findKeyword` does the same - prints that keyword not in list.

How can I fix the code so it runs for any list?

Code:

```
NodeT *addNewKeyword(NodeT **list, char *keyword) {
    NodeT *new = malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    assert(new != NULL);
    strcpy(new->keyword, keyword);
    new->next = *list;
    *list = new;
    return 0;
}

LinkT *addNewLink(NodeT *list, char *link) {
    LinkT *new = malloc(sizeof(LinkT));
    assert(new != NULL);
    strcpy(new->link, link);
    new->next = list->links;
    list->links = new;
    return 0;
}

NodeT *findKeyword(NodeT *list, char *keyword) {
    NodeT *current = list;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->keyword, keyword) == 0) {
            return current;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *findLink (NodeT *list, char *keyword, char *link) {
    NodeT *current = list;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->keyword, keyword) == 0) {
            
            LinkT *currentLink = list->links;

            while (currentLink != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(currentLink->link, link) == 0) {
                    return currentLink;
                }
                currentLink = list->links->next;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *printList(NodeT *listNode) {
    while (listNode != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", listNode->keyword);

        LinkT *listLink = listNode->links;
        if (listLink == NULL) {
            printf("List is empty.\n");
        } else {
            while (listLink != NULL) {
                printf("    %s\n", listLink->url);
                listLink = listLink->next;
            }
        }
        listNode = listNode->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    NodeT *wordsList = NULL; 

    addNewKeyword(&wordsList, "Moon");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-1");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-3");

    addNewKeyword(&wordsList, "Earth");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-2");
    
    /* runs after removing following lines: */
    // addNewKeyword(&wordsList, "Asteroid");
    // addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-23");
    // addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-45");

    if (findKeyword(wordsList, "Moon") == 0) {
        printf("Keyword is in list.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Keyword is not in list.\n");
    }

    if (findLink(wordsList, "Moon", "Link-1") == NULL) {
        printf("Link is not in list.\n");
        addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-1");
    } else {
        printf("Link is in list.\n");
    }

    printList(wordsList);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I'm returning a node from a function type void, which might be the reason to don't work as expected. What type is the `findLink` function needs to be?

**EDIT 2**

As was pointed out in answers by Sahin, I updated the `findLink` function and now the program runs, but adding an element to incorrect place. Change in main code:

```
int main() {
    ...
    addNewKeyword(&wordsList, "Moon");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-1");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-3");

    addNewKeyword(&wordsList, "Earth");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-2");
    
    addNewKeyword(&wordsList, "Asteroid");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-23");
    addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-45");

    if (findLink(wordsList, "Earth", "Link-4") == NULL) {
        printf("Link is not in list.\n");
        addNewLink(wordsList, "Link-4");
    } else {
        printf("Link is in list.\n");
    }
    ...
}
```

Output:

```
Link is not in list.
Asteroid
    Link-4
    Link-45
    Link-23
Earth
    Link-2
Moon
    Link-3
    Link-1
```

Comment: And what specific problem do you have with the code shown? Please provide the input, expected result and actual result. Most importantly please provide complete code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @kaylum I have edited the question.

Comment: In addNewKeyword you dereference the first parameter (list) but when called the first time, list is NULL.
    `NodeT *wordsList = NULL; 

    addNewKeyword(&wordsList, "Moon");`

Comment: @AndersK how can I fix this?

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Do you want to add a new Link to Earth and not to Asteroid? I am updating my answer, please provide more things.

Comment: @Sahin sorry for the confusion, I made some changes. Yes, I would like to add a new link to whatever keyword specified when the `findLink` is called - in this case it will be Earth; if it would be Mars, then it should add a new link to Mars links list.

Comment: @DSzum then, you need to remove the line that I have commented on, and before adding new Link you need to find the NodeT that you want to add the Link on, give it as parameter in addNewKeyword function. And finally upvote me :)

Comment: @Sahin thank you, but why do I pass it as a parameter in addNewKeyword function? I'm adding a new link element, shouldn't it be passed to addNewLink?

Comment: Sorry you are right. You need to find the pointer to the list you want the Link to be added and pass it to this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void *findLink (NodeT *list, char *keyword, char *link) {
    NodeT *current = list;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->keyword, keyword) == 0) {
            
            LinkT *currentLink = current->links;//An error is here, you always look for the same list.

            while (currentLink != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(currentLink->link, link) == 0) {
                    return currentLink;
                }
                currentLink = currentLink->next;//The other error is here
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I guess your error is here, you need to get the next of the currentLink, since the next of the same node will always be the same. You need to test the code after doing these corrections, then we can look the results again.

EDIT:
In response to edit 2:

```
NodeT *addNewKeyword(NodeT **list, char *keyword) {
    NodeT *new = malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
    assert(new != NULL);
    strcpy(new->keyword, keyword);
    new->next = *list;
    *list = new; //This row
    return 0;
}
```

In the row that I put a comment, you change the value inside the parameter and the value in the list variable changes. Since you call addNeKeyword with "Asteroid" at last, the new Links are added to there. So, please specify more details. What do you really want?

Comment: Alright, now it runs, but adds a new link to the incorrect keyword. I will add new edit to the post now.